# MSBuild-Referenced DLLs not copying to output bin

Tags: msbuild

I was a newbie, a little bit knowledge of visual studio, msbuild and scripting.

I was assigned to a task, to create an automation script for building project using MSbuild and the project has three different configuration and I need to build it sequentially because some projects depend on the output dlls of the other configuration, when building the first configuration it succeed but when I reach the second and third configuration it failed. Because reference DLLs were not copied on the ouput bin of selected configuration causing it to missing assembly reference on some projects. And, the thing is I can't edit the projects, it was only for me to view.

Any help on how could I successfully build it.

My script looks like this:

```
& $msbuild ($master_sln) /t:Clean /p:Configuration=FirstConfiguration /p:Platform="Any CPU"
& $msbuild ($master_sln) /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=FirstConfiguration /p:Platform="Any CPU" 

& $msbuild ($master_sln) /t:Build /p:Configuration="SecondConfiguration" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false 

& $msbuild ($master_sln) /t:Build /p:Configuration="ThirdConfiguration" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

Comment: You don't need to clean before rebuild, rebuild = clean+build. Also: you use /p:BuildProjectReferences=false. How about just leaving that set to true so dependent projects are built (and dlls copied)? In the other case: you don't provide enough information to come up with an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections @stijn. And sorry but I only have that information as of now, but if you have situation like that how can you build a solution in different configuration in an order like that. just a sequence or an idea. Thank you very much.